# Unable to Move/Copy files - Cannot find the specified file

Tags: file-management, file-transfer, windows-server-2003, copy-paste, cut-and-paste

Got this really odd issue whereby I'm unable to copy/move any .tif files from multiple locations on two file servers to a new server. Whenever the copy reaches a .tif file it fails with the error "Cannot find the file specified".

I can copy it locally to the same drive but not to a USB hard or a shared location on another server.

It only seems to affect .tif files for some reason.

Any thoughts on where I even begin to start troubleshooting?

Thanks

Comment: Are your tif filenames long such that the total pathname exceeds 256 characters?

Comment: Hey Peter, nah really small like 15 characters with the extension and only maybe 40 with the full path as well. Its so odd driving me mental!

Comment: Permissions? ...

Comment: If the servers are networked, can you try copying a tif file from the destination server rather than pushing it from the originating server?

Comment: Hey David, All seems fine I can move it to another location (another local HD) Security shows my rights as full control. So moving from D to C is fine, moving from D or C to USB or to \\xxx\xxx\xxx it fails, I can move all over files to these locations until I reach a TIF and then it stops with this stupid error!

Comment: @PeterFowler Yeah pulling instead of pushing let me try that!

Comment: @PeterFowler That actually works cannot believe I didn't think to try it, been messing around for ages on that Server to try and get it to move! Thanks, happy to accept as an answer if you want to add it although still not sure exactly why this behaving is happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the servers are networked, can you try copying a tif file from the destination server rather than pushing it from the originating server?